# JQuery ajax JSON data data missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following JSON data - response from PAYPAL purchase

```html
{
  "create_time": "2021-04-07T20:39:16Z",
  "update_time": "2021-04-07T20:39:36Z",
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "payer": {
    "email_address": "sb@personal.example.com",
    "payer_id": "xxxxx",
    "address": {
      "country_code": "CA"
    },
    "name": {
      "given_name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe"
    }
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "description": "Book",
      "reference_id": "default",
      "amount": {
        "value": "50.00",
        "currency_code": "CAD",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "value": "50.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "shipping": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "handling": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "insurance": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "shipping_discount": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          }
        }
      },
      "payee": {
        "email_address": "sb@business.example.com",
        "merchant_id": "xxxx"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Book",
          "unit_amount": {
            "value": "50.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "tax": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "CAD"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ],
      "payments": {
        "captures": [
          {
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "id": "xxxx",
            "final_capture": true,
            "create_time": "2021-04-07T20:39:36Z",
            "update_time": "2021-04-07T20:39:36Z",
            "amount": {
              "value": "50.00",
              "currency_code": "CAD"
            },
            "seller_protection": {
              "status": "ELIGIBLE",
              "dispute_categories": [
                "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
              ]
            },
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/xxxx",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET",
                "title": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/xxxx/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST",
                "title": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxxx",
                "rel": "up",
                "method": "GET",
                "title": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxxx",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET",
      "title": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

The json above is copied from the console (below).  Items is the returned transaction data from Paypal:

```
var items_json          = JSON.stringify(details); 
console.log (items_json);
```

if I am sending this json via javascript Jquery AJAX to a php script, some of the data is missing

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",

    data : {

            G_test: items_json,

            },
    url: "xxxx.php", 
    success: function( data ) 
    { 



    },
    error: function( xhr, status, thrown )
    {

    }
});
```

Here is what is posted from the browser inspector -- invalid json:

```js
{
  "create_time":"2021-04-07T20:39:16Z",
  "update_time":"2021-04-07T20:39:36Z",
  "id":"xxxx",
  "intent":"CAPTURE",
  "status":"COMPLETED",
  "payer":  {
    "email_address":"sb@personal.example.com",
    "payer_id":"xxxx",
    "address":  {
      "country_code":"CA"
    },
    "name": {
      "given_name":"John",
      "surname":"Doe"
    }
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "description":"Book",
      "reference_id":"default",
      "amount": {
        "value":"50.00",
        "currency_code":"CAD",
        ** SHOULD BE "breakdown"...missing data from here
        "bre…xxID of transactionxxxxx", // data is truncated here bre...
        "rel":"self",
        "method":"GET",
        "title":"GET"
       },
      {
        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/xxxx/refund",
        "rel":"refund",
        "method":"POST",
        "title":"POST"
        
      },
      {
        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxxx",
        "rel":"up",
        "method":"GET",
        "title":"GET"
        
      }
    ]
      
    }
    ]
  
}
}
]
,"links": [
  {
    "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxxx",
    "rel":"self",
    "method":"GET",
    "title":"GET"
    
  }
]
}
```

I am positive I had this working a while back, but now it is creating invalid json data (missing data).
Any ideas?

Comment: You're sending a String, wrapped in an Object, that is wrapped in an Object to your PHP. I suspect the structure is more complex than you intended and PHP is not reading from the proper index.

Comment: You should send `{ G_test: details }` (or just `details`) and not mess around with stringified stuff.

Comment: What do you get if you run `var_export($_POST['G_test'])` in your PHP?

Comment: this is crazy...now it works after 2 days of fighting with this.   All I needed t do was post in stackoverflow....